# xCHM can't open any of chm file

Tags: 14.04, chm

My xCHM Reader can't open any file. When I try to open a chm file I get this error:

```
../src/common/unichar.cpp(65): assert "Assert failure" failed in ToHi8bit(): character cannot be converted to single byte
```

[image]

Comment: The file contains a multi-byte character that `xchm` cannot convert to a single byte. This might mean that your `.chm` file is corrupt. Do you experience the problem on other `.chm` files?

Comment: Can you open the CHM file in [other CHM viewers](/q/8205/175814), with Wine (`wine hh file.chm`), or in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

The program "Archmage" can solve this problem. Just install it from repository and type in command line:

```
$ archmage 'name_of_your_chm_file'*
```

`chm-file` is an html archive, you will see a result of this operaion in the folder with your chm-file name + '_html' extension.